# How can I vertically align items inside v-text-field and v-select components

Tags: css, vue.js, layout, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a toolbar in my Vue app. After a long session, I finalized it but I still have a general problem with aligning items, especially inside the v-text-field and v-select components. The problem is that I tried different options but I feel like there is something wrong or I didn't understand vuetify at all. Here is a list of the problems:

1-The inner items of select and the search icon inside the v-text-field are aligned to the bottom of its parent. How can I vertically align it to the center?

2-I put a max-width for the search bar but its parent is not affected by that. Therefore, the text (Detayli Arama) that comes after it cannot be aligned right next to it.

[image: The screenshot of the toolbar]

The code is:

```
<v-text-field
      hide-details
      height="30px"
      outlined
      dense
      single-line
      append-icon="search"
      class="ml-12"
      placeholder="Kelime, ilan no veya mağaza adı ile ara"
    ></v-text-field>
    <a target="_blank" href @click.stop v-on="on">
      <h5 class="subheading primary--text">Detaylı Arama</h5>
    </a>

    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <a target="_blank" href @click.stop v-on="on">
      <v-icon small left color="grey darken-2">email</v-icon>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href @click.stop v-on="on">
      <v-icon left small color="grey darken-2">notifications</v-icon>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href @click.stop v-on="on">
      <v-icon left small color="grey darken-2">star</v-icon>
    </a>

    <v-select
      v-model="userSelect"
      :items="items"
      height="30px"
      label="Kullanıcı"
      outlined
      dense
      hide-details
      left
      single-line
      class="shrink"
      style="max-width:220px"
    ></v-select>
```

Styling is handled in main.css

```
.v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot {
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 10px !important;
}

.v-input__control {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.v-select {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```